# VueJs: How to update the width of an element based on another?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am building a Trivia app, and I have an `<h1>` element that changes every 10 seconds. I want to match the width of a radio button group component (`b-form-group` is a [Bootstrap-Vue component](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-radio/#button-style-radios)) with the width of the `<h1>` element. Something like this:

[image: example image of the desired output]
I tried using `watchers` to update `buttonWidth` whenever the value of `question` changes. But, with this code, the width of the button group seems to match the width of the previous question instead of the current one. I also tried other properties like `updated`, `mounted`, `created`. I am just not able to get it to work correctly. Is there an easier way to match the width of two elements?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="question">
       <h1 ref="quest">{{ question }}</h1>
    </div>

    <b-form-group>
      <b-form-radio-group :style=getWidth
        ref="opts"
        :options="options"
        buttons
        stacked
        button-variant="outline-primary"
        size="lg"
        name="radio-btn-stacked"
      ></b-form-radio-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>
```

Under my Script I have:

```
export default {
  props: ['question', 'options'],
  data() {
    return {
      buttonWidth: '0 px',
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  watch: {
    question() {
      // console.log('Updating button width to ', this.$refs.quest.clientWidth);
      this.buttonWidth = `width: ${this.$refs.quest.clientWidth}px;`;
    },
    // immediate: true,
  },
  computed: {
    getWidth() {
      return this.buttonWidth;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

To get it working with a `watch` you'd need a `$nextTick`, otherwise the component won't have re-rendered yet and you'll still be measuring the old width:

```js
watch: {
  question() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.buttonWidth = `width: ${this.$refs.quest.clientWidth}px;`;
    })
  }
}
```

It should also be possible to get this working with the `mounted` and `updated` hooks instead of a `watch`. You shouldn't need `$nextTick` if you do it that way. You mentioned that you've tried that in the question but without seeing the code you tried it's difficult to know why that didn't work for you.

Also, it's not clear why you have a computed property called `getWidth`. Why not just use `buttonWidth` directly?

Comment: You were right about not requiring the computed property. The reason I had it because I was trying out different things since I was not getting the desired output. 
I had also previously tried the $nextTick(). I finally discovered my mistake. I had to use `span` inside my `h1` and get the offsetWidth. clientWidth wasn't returning the exact width of the text.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was using the `clientWidth` of the `h1` tag. This wasn't returning the width of the text in pixels, instead, it was returning the entire width of the div. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```js
<template>
  <div class="text-center center">
    <div id="question">
       <h1 ref="quest"><span ref="span">{{ question }}</span></h1>
    </div>

    <b-form-group>
      <b-form-radio-group :style=buttonWidth
        ref="opts"
        :options="options"
        buttons
        stacked
        button-variant="outline-primary"
        size="lg"
        name="radio-btn-stacked"
      ></b-form-radio-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['question', 'options'],
  data() {
    return {
      buttonWidth: 'width: 500px',
      value: 0,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    question() {
      console.log('Watcher is updating buttonWidth to ', this.$refs.quest.clientWidth);
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$refs.span.offsetWidth);
        this.buttonWidth = `width: ${this.$refs.span.offsetWidth}px;`;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```